# Let $H$ be normal of order $6$. If $f:G\to G_1$ be an epi. of groups s.t. $H\subset\ker(f)$, then show $G_1$ is also a hom. image of $G/H$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-homomorphism

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of order $6$. If $f :G\longrightarrow G_1$ be an epimorphism of groups such that $H\subset \ker(f)$, then show that $G_1$ is also a homomorphic image of $G/H$.

My solution goes as follows:

> We consider, $\phi:G/H\longrightarrow G_1$, such that $\phi(Hg)=f(g)$. Then, we see that, $\forall Hg_1,Hg_2\in G/H$, $\phi(Hg_1Hg_2)=f(g_1g_2)=f(g_1)f(g_2)=\phi(Hg_1)\phi(Hg_2)$. So, $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Also, $\forall p\in G_1$,$\exists g\in G$, such that $f(g)=p$ and hence $\phi(Hg)=f(g)=p$. Hence, $f$ is onto. Therefore, $G_1$ is also a homomorphic image of $G/H$.

Is the above solution, correct? If not, where is it going wrong?

Comment: Don't use "epi" as a synonym for "surjective". Epimorphism means "right cancellable", and there are classes of groups where epimorphisms need not be surjective. E.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9807117).

Comment: You don't say whose subgroup $H$ is, and instead force the reader to deduce it later from the condition on the kernel.

Comment: The order of $H$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Do you know about the *3rd Isomorphism Theorem* for groups: it follows that $G_1 \cong (G/H)/(ker(f)/H)$. As Arturo points out, the order of $H$ is irrelevant.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thank you so much! No, actually, in the homomorphism chapter of I.N Herstein (I am followingTopics in Algebra by I.N Herstein), only first isomorphism theorem is stated and the third isomorphism theorem is not given, if I can recall correctly. Yes, as I clarified in my previous comment, the order is irrelevant .

Comment: @NickyHekster But,is my solution alright?

Comment: Yes, except that you need to check that your $\phi$ is well-defined: it is not dependening on the particular representative $g$ of the coset $Hg$. Here you need that the $ker(f) \subset H$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Can you please explain, when do we need to check that whether a function is well defined or not? Is there a general criteria for checking it? Also, when can one avoid checking whether a function is well-defined or not. This is because, in many proofs I see some of them doesnt check for any well-defineness of a function ?...

Comment: Well, for cosets the representative is not unique, for example if you look at a right coset $Hg (H \leq G, g \in G)$, then also $hg, (h \in H)$ is a representative of the *same* coset ($Hg=Hhg$). Hence a map that depends on cosets needs this kind of checking. There are many instances in mathematics were a certain concept can be represented by different entities (another example: conjugacy classes) yet denotes the same thing. Hope this helps.

Comment: @NickyHekster Thanks a lot! But how to prove that it is well-defined in this case?

Comment: If $Hg_1=Hg_2$, then $g_1g_2^{-1} \in H \subset ker(f)$. So $f(g_1g_2^{-1})=1$, implying ($f$ is a homomorphism) $\phi(Hg_1) = f(g_1)=f(g_2)=\phi(Hg_2)$.